# Distributed development with Git

Tags: git

Can someone show/point/help me to a resource for distributed development Git example or guide?

I'm a newbie and through I tried to google, I'm overwhelmed by the amount of information available.

My situation is that I have few developers around the globe and and ideally we don't have to deal with a central repository like Svn, but still have a central repository to track changes and publish diff to a blogspot account or something.

Comment: I found Pro Git to be a good resource too, http://progit.org

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The resources listed at the [official Git site's documentation section](http://git-scm.com/documentation) are actually quite good at covering the basics. See the links under the 'Tutorials' header especially.

Comment: The `gitworkflows` man page may be exactly what he is looking for:

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitworkflows.html

Answer (score 3):

If you ever used SVN, you can take a look at http://git.or.cz/course/svn.html.

Also, [gittutorial](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gittutorial.html) might give a good start too.

If you are developing an open source project, take a look at http://github.com - that would provide a lot of useful features.

Answer (score 3):

If you feel comfortable on the command line, I recommend John Wiegle's [Git from the bottom up](http://ftp.newartisans.com/pub/git.from.bottom.up.pdf). It does a good job of showing the workings of git without teaching a "preferred" work flow.

Answer (score 2):

[GitHub](http://github.com/) is a free service you can use to host your repositories and they make it very easy to work between developers (in addition to other features such as wiki hosting).  Also, they've got a great set of [guides](http://github.com/guides/home) for getting started.  I'd start there if I were you.

Comment: Ya, unfortunately it's a closed source, and we are trying to do without any paid service. So my goal is to see how we can make do without having a central repo.

Comment: I guess, this kind of model workflow is well documented in the docs already, but having tried that for a while, I want to know real world cases of how ppl make it work.

Comment: I would suggest looking at gitosis for hosting your central git repo. Then it is easy to publish your changes in case you're behind NATs. I myself host it on an Ubuntu 9.04 VM at RackspaceCloud.com. http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way explains how to set it up easily.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to pull down a copy of Git, make yourself a tiny dummy "project" (or take a small existing one and import its sources), and play around with it.

I found working with git so different from working with a centralized revision control system that I really had to do this to begin to wrap my mind around how it works and how it could be used for our developers.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you don't want to end up using github for your specific project in the end, I've found github to be a simple way to get at the best practices of setting up git, because the setup stages are documented along the way in steps, e.g. create your github account > add your public key to the server > create a local repository and a starting commit > set up the remote repository as your origin > push to your new origin.  For me, it made it simpler to use the site as a guide to the process until I was very familiar with the steps involved.

Gitorious.com may do that as well and have the added benefit (slight unless the featureset gets bigger than github) of being open source, I haven't really worked with that site enough to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

In the cases, like yours, (developers around the globe), its obvious to use DVCS, rather that Centralized VC like SVN.

Get used to it, here is something to learn and like GIT. [Get it](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html)

Comment: Judging from the original question, I'm fairly sure Seymour has already decided to use Git (or at least is strongly leaning towards it).

Comment: That's true, I'm already using it. Just not good enough and pretty we could do better.